# Wikipedia's intrinsic definition of differential forms query

Tags: differential-forms

The “Intrinsic definitions” section of the Wikipedia article on differential forms [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form#Intrinsic_definitions) states:

> By the universal property of exterior powers, this is equivalently an
> alternating multilinear map:
>
> $$\beta_{p}:\bigoplus_{n=1}^{k}T_{p}M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}.$$

Where $\beta_{p}$ is a $k$-form at point $p$. Can anyone provide a not too technical explanation as to what that means? From Wikipedia I sort of understand that $\oplus$ is a direct sum (eg $\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R}$ gives $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, the Cartesian plane). But what does the direct sum of tangent spaces mean? And how does this give an alternating multilinear map? Is it more or less saying that a $k$-form acts on $k$ tangent vectors to give a real number?

Comment: You can form the direct sum of vector spaces (over the same field), and $T_pM$ is a real vector space.

Comment: Not every map $\bigoplus_{n=1}^{k}T_{p}M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is alternating. But some are, and those can be identified as $k$-forms.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese - I'm only just learning about direct sums so forgive my ignorance. Are we here talking about an outer/external direct sum of $k$ tangent spaces $T_pM$?

Comment: Yes, it is an external direct sum of $k$ copies of the same vector space $T_pM$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese - That's clearer, now. Thanks. Don't suppose you have a reference for the above direct sum expression? I haven't been able to find it anywhere except in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: This is just multilinear algebra, so I would check books on that topic.

Comment: For any real vector space $V$, there is a natural map $\pi : \bigoplus_{n=1}^kV \to \bigwedge^kV$ given by $(v_1, \dots, v_k) \mapsto v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_k$. Now, if $L : \bigwedge^kV \to \mathbb{R}$ is a linear map, one obtains a linear map $L\circ\pi: \bigoplus_{n=1}^kV \to \mathbb{R}$ which is alternating. Conversely, given an alternating linear map $\hat{L} : \bigoplus_{n=1}^kV \to \mathbb{R}$, there is a unique linear map $L : \bigwedge^kV \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\hat{L} = L\circ\pi$. This seems to me to be the thing you don't understand. Would you agree?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese So if $k=2$, for example, there's some kind of a function or map that changes $\left(v_{1},v_{2}\right)$ to $v_{1}\wedge v_{2}$, where $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ are copies of $V$? And that function/map (which involves wedge products) is what makes your $L\circ\pi:\bigoplus_{n=1}^{k}V\to\mathbb{R}$ alternating? I hope I've got that right. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: The map is $\pi$. Given $v_1, v_2 \in V$, we have $\pi(v_1, v_2) = v_1\wedge v_2 \in\bigwedge^2V$. Now, for any linear map $L : \bigwedge^2V \to \mathbb{R}$, we have $(L\circ \pi)(v_1, v_1) = L(\pi(v_1, v_1)) = L(v_1\wedge v_1) = L(0) = 0$; i.e. the linear map $L\circ \pi : V\oplus V \to \mathbb{R}$ is alternating.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Right, so $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ are elements of $V$, not copies of $V$. That's easier for me to understand. So I'm hoping that $L\circ\pi$ in your $L\circ\pi:V\oplus V\to\mathbb{R}$ is a 2-form?

Comment: $L$ and $L\circ \pi$ are two equivalent ways of viewing a two-form.

Comment: It is not claiming that EVERY such map is a k-form. It merely says that a k-form can be seen as such a map (with extra properties.)

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese - But why isn't the (linear?) map $\pi$ also alternating, given that (in my $k=2$ example) I can say $\pi\left(v_{1},v_{1}\right)=\left(v_{1}\wedge v_{1}\right)=0$?

Comment: It is an alternating linear map, but it is not an alternating linear map to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Dohhhh!! I should have seen that. Is $L\circ\pi$ in $L\circ\pi:\bigoplus_{n=1}^{k}V\to\mathbb{R}$ a differential form only when $V$ is the tangent space $T_{P}M$? I'd be more than happy to accept your main comments as an answer, by the way.

Comment: Yes. I will write an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. A *differential $k$-form* on $M$ is a smooth section of the bundle $\varpi : \bigwedge^kT^*M \to M$, i.e. a map $\beta : M \to \bigwedge^kT^*M$, $p \mapsto \beta_p$ such that $\varpi\circ\beta = \operatorname{id}_M$. In particular, $\beta_p \in \bigwedge^kT_p^*M$ for every $p$. So a differential $k$-form on $M$ can be thought of as a collection $\{\beta_p\}_{p \in M}$ where $\beta_p$ varies smoothly as $p$ varies.

To understand what $\beta_p$ is, note that under the isomorphism $\bigwedge^k T_p^*M \cong \left(\bigwedge^kT_pM\right)^*$, the element $\beta_p$ of the left hand side corresponds to an element of the right hand side (which I will also denote by $\beta_p$), a linear map $\beta_p : \bigwedge^kT_pM \to \mathbb{R}$.

There is a natural multilinear map $\pi : \bigoplus_{i=1}^kT_pM \to \bigwedge^k T_pM$ given by $(v_1, \dots, v_k) \mapsto v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_k$. Precomposing $\beta_p$ with this map, we obtain a multilinear map $\beta_p\circ\pi : \bigoplus_{i=1}^kT_pM \to \mathbb{R}$. Note that if $v_i = v_j$ for some $i \neq j$, then $\pi(v_1, \dots, v_k) = 0$ and hence $(\beta_p\circ\pi)(v_1, \dots, v_k) = 0$; that is, $\beta_p\circ\pi : \bigoplus_{i=1}^kT_pM \to \mathbb{R}$ is an alternating multilinear map.

The correspondence between linear maps $\bigwedge^kT_pM \to \mathbb{R}$ and alternating multilinear maps $\bigoplus_{i=1}^k T_pM \to \mathbb{R}$ given by precomposing with $\pi$ is bijective. In particular, for every alternating multilinear map $\hat{L} : \bigoplus_{i=1}^kT_pM \to \mathbb{R}$, there is a unique linear map $L : \bigwedge^kT_pM \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\hat{L} = L\circ\pi$. The map $L$ is constructed by defining $L(v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_k) := \hat{L}(v_1, \dots, v_k)$ and extending linearly.

What the previous paragraph tells us is that the map $\beta_p\circ\pi : \bigoplus_{i=1}^kT_pM \to \mathbb{R}$ is uniquely determined by $\beta_p$. This is why Wikipedia also uses $\beta_p$ to denote the map which I have called $\beta_p\circ\pi$.